# Efficient way to use If statement for checking the value is not being used in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have four textboxes say textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4 in my HTML doc on a button click for btn1 I want to make sure that all the values entered in all four textboxes are distinct & unique. For which I am using the if condition.

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function(){

    if($("#textbox1").val() === $("#textbox2").val() || 
       $("#textbox1").val() === $("#textbox3").val() ||
       $("#textbox1").val() === $("#textbox4").val() ||
       $("#textbox2").val() === $("#textbox3").val() || 
       $("#textbox2").val() === $("#textbox4").val() ||
       $("#textbox3").val() === $("#textbox4").val() ) 
    {  alert("Values are not unique please check them."); }

});
```

Is there any way shorter than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a set with an array. The set removes dupes so if the length does not match, there was dupes.

```js
function checkIfArrayIsUnique(myArray) {
  return myArray.length === new Set(myArray).size;
}

$("button").on("click", function () {
  var vals = $(".tb").map( function () { return this.value }).get()
  console.log(checkIfArrayIsUnique(vals))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="tb" />
<input type="text" class="tb" />
<input type="text" class="tb" />
<input type="text" class="tb" />

<button type="button">Check</button>
```

You may want to "normalize" the values if you are looking for unique text without case. Example "aaa" vs "AAA"....

Comment: In this case, is it possible to stop comparison of blank values (empty text boxes) because blank will also lead the condition to be false.

Comment: $(".tb").filter(function () { return this.value.length }).map....

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of checking the uniqueness.

- On a button, click push all the values into an array
- Check the duplicates in array Use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- If duplicate count is greater than 0 its mean values are duplicated.

For example

```js
let fruits = ['Apple', 'apple', 'AppLE', 'Orange', 'ORANGE'];
let duplicates = new Map(fruits.map(s => [s.toLowerCase(), s]));

console.log([...duplicates.values()]);
```

... is a spread operator [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)